# The probability that the difference between the maximum and minimum of the received numbers does not exceed 27

Tags: probability-theory

25 random different numbers from 1 to 90 are taken. What is the probability that the difference between the maximum and minimum of the resulting numbers does not exceed 27?

The idea of my solution is simply to search through the possible combinations. For example, a sequence of numbers from 1 to 25, or from 1 to 26, but with one skip, is suitable. However, this solution does not look very nice.

Comment: You need more information. Are the numbers equally likely? Are they sampled with or without replacement? etc.

Comment: @Gregory I don't really understand about the replacement, but the numbers are equal probability. Numbers from 1 to 90 are unique, and if a number has already been taken before, it cannot be taken again.

Comment: With replacement means that if you take a number, it could be used again.

Comment: @Gregory no, it can't be used again

Comment: To me - it seems intuitive that this chance will be rather low. Choosing 10 numbers from 1-90, you can imagine that places one number in equal sized groups (1-9, 10-18,etc.). Then it seems likely that your range $R \approx 80$. I'd imagine the probability is near much less than 1%. Unfortunately you can't do much but calculate this numerically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the general problem where draw $k$ numbers without replacement from the integers $1\dots N$. Define the maximum number $M_k$ and the minimum $m_k$.

To find the probability $P(M_k=j)$, note that the remaining $k-1$ draws must be chosen from the integers $1 \dots j- 1$ (the largest is fixed at $j$). This is just a counting problem and so
$$ P(M_k = j) = \frac{\binom{j-1}{k-1}}{\binom{N}{k}}, \quad j = k,\dots,N. $$

An analogous story occurs with the minimum $P(m_k = j)$. The remaining $k-1$ draws occurs between integers $j+1, \dots N$. Thus,
$$ P(m_k = j) = \frac{\binom{N-j}{k-1}}{\binom{N}{k}}, \quad j = 1, \dots,N-k+1. $$

Let $R_k = M_k - m_k$ be the range. Then
\begin{align}
P(R_k = r) & = \sum_{j=k}^N P(R_k = r | M_k = j) P(M_k = j) \\
& = \sum_{j=k}^N P(m_k = j - r | M_k = j) \frac{\binom{j-1}{k-1}}{\binom{N}{k}} \\
& = \sum_{j=\max(k,r+1)}^N \frac{\binom{r-1}{k-2}}{\binom{j-1}{k-1}} \frac{\binom{j-1}{k-1}}{\binom{N}{k}} \\
& = \frac{\binom{r-1}{k-2}}{\binom{N}{k}}(N - r), \quad r = k-1, \dots N-1.
\end{align}
The third line follows by noting that if the maximum is set to $j$, then the minimum out of the remaining $k-1$ draws ranges from $1,\dots,j-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Think like this: the answer to your question can be found if you answer the following: what is the probability of an event in which you create sorted array of numbers from 1 to 90 and difference between minumum and maximum will be less than 25 and remaining 23 numbers are fitted between them. It is slightly easier.
The probability of the first part of this event is or more precisely of event when you pick two numbers (min and max) and their difference is $\delta$:

$p(\delta) = \frac{90-\delta+1}{\frac{90*89}{2}}$

Next you need to calculate the probability $p(A|\delta)$  where $A - $all remaining numbers are fitted between min and max. It is school math actually. If $\delta=27$, then first number you can pick $26$ from $88$ numbers and so on, so:

$p(A|\delta) = \frac{(\delta-1)!*(88-(25-2))!}{88!*((\delta-1)-(25-2))!} = \frac{(\delta-1)!*65!}{88!*(\delta-24)!}$

Then sum $p(A|\delta)*p(\delta)$ for all $\delta$ from $n-1$ to $m$ to find $p(A)$, where $n$ - number of numbers to pick and $m$ - max $\delta$. The answer, I suppose, is:

$\frac{(90-n)!}{90!}\sum_{\delta=n-1}^m \frac{(\delta-1)!}{(\delta-n+1)!}$